# Why is WebBrowser.Dispose() launching Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

I have a Form that contains a WebBrowser. Sometimes, when calling it's Dispose method, Internet Explorer opens and loads the page that was loaded in my WebBrowser. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Well actually, it's a class derived from WebBrowser. I'm not overriding WebBrowser's Dispose's method. Could this be the problem? And if it is, what should I do in the Dispose method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is sometimes WebBrowser.Dispose() launching Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671221/why-is-sometimes-webbrowser-dispose-launching-internet-explorer)

Comment: jsoldi: You should just have upgraded this question. Don't start a new one just to add some code.